# CSS font styles not showing up in website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm very new to coding and I'm currently trying to build a simple header and navigation bar using HTML and CSS.

So far, this is my CSS code:

```
     * {   text-decoration: none; }

     body {   background-color: #f3f3f3; }

     header {   background-color: #fff;   width: 100%;   height: 100px; }

     header .header-logo {   font-family: Montserrat;   font-size: 24px;  
     font-weight: 900;   color: #111;   text-transform: uppercase;  
     display: block;   margin: 0 auto;   text-align: center;   padding:
     20px 0; }

     header nav ul {

     }

     header nav ul li { display: inline-block; float: left; list-style:
     none; }

     header nav ul li a {   font-family: Montserrat;   font-size: 24px;  
     font-weight: 900;   color: #111; }
```

However, when I view my website in the browser, it seems the font-weight and color are not showing up (in the header-logo).

And the navigation font does not add any styles (font, size, weight or color).

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" class="header-logo">Moving Animals</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html"></a>Portfolio</li>
        <li><a href="about.html"></a>About</li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"></a>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="cases.html" class="header-cases">Cases</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>

  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong, it would be highly appreciated as I'm determined to learn how to build websites. Thanks for your time.

Update: Just finally seen that the Portfolio, About, and Contact should be between the  rather than the  - have changed and the nav bar seems to be working slightly.

The problem now is the font-weight does not change in either header, any ideas? And thanks again!

Comment: Can you show your `<head></head>` HTML so we can see how you've linked your stylesheet?

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 sure, I've added now - thanks

Comment: do you see any error on the browser's console of network tab using the dev tools?

Comment: Just finally seen that the Portfolio, About, and Contact should be between the <a></a> rather than the </li> - have changed and the nav bar seems to be working slightly. The problem now is the font-weight does not change in either header

Comment: @Aniket Kariya (dots) are only used when specifying a class name. The `<header>` tag in the question doesn't have a class, so the way it's specified in the css is correct. It's like how you can target all `<div>` tags in your css by simply doing `div {...}`

Comment: @AniketKariya that seems to break it as all of the styling disappears

Comment: @AJones if you add `!important` to the end of your css rule for font-weight, does that make it work? e.g. `font-weight:900!important;`

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 you're a genius, it does! Could you explain this for me a little?

Comment: `!important` tag basically overrides any other styles that are currently placed on the tag. So somewhere in your stylesheet (or 3rd party stylesheet if you're using one) will be another `font-weight` code that is taking precedent over yours. Ideally, you shouldn't use `!important` tags, and instead try and find the overwriting code, or actually specify the tag that the class belongs to e.g. `a.header-logo` - but at least you now know what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `header-logo` is a class used directly on a link (i.e. an `a` tag), I would extend its selector: Change it from  `header .header-logo`  to `header a.header-logo`, otherwise default link classes might overwrite it.

Actually you might even want to add the `:link`, `:visited` , `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes to the `a` tag in seperate selectors.

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you so much - if you have time, could you just explain by default link classes would overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the color and weight attribute as inline fields in your html page, As I think your values are being over-written.

As per my suggestion,

while you are designing a web page, I suggest that you use inline elements to test whether you styles are working then move to a .css file.

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful advice - I will definitely do so in the future

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code to your header add `class="header-logo"` as you mentioned in css

```
<header class="header-logo">hey</header>
```

and this following code of yours:

```
 header .header-logo {   font-family: Montserrat;   font-size: 24px;  
 font-weight: 900;   color: #111;   text-transform: uppercase;  
 display: block;   margin: 0 auto;   text-align: center;   padding:
 20px 0; }
```

do this just remove single space after `header .header-logo` to `header.header-logo` 
like below :

```
 header.header-logo {   font-family: Montserrat;   font-size: 24px;  
 font-weight: 900;   color: #111;   text-transform: uppercase;  
 display: block;   margin: 0 auto;   text-align: center;   padding:
 20px 0; }
```

I tried doing this and it worked for me [Answer to **CSS font styles not showing up in website** thread](https://codepen.io/mitsukiOrochimaru/pen/omEXLe)

Comment: hey, thanks for your help! I think the difference with our code is that my html is: <body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" class="header-logo">Moving Animals</a>

whereas yours does not have the index linked (it seems I need the index linked otherwise it breaks) and if I remove the space, it breaks, too